# Getting warning message for Template Tags while updating from EE5 to EE6

Tags: ee6

After the successful update, I am getting a warning message about the below template tags on the success page that the template tags are not found.

```
{exp:mailinglist:form}
{exp:trackback:url}
{exp:trackback:entries}
{exp:referrer}
{exp:emoticon}
```

should we take care of it? or these addons removed from EE6?

Answer (score 1):

In ExpressionEngine 6 we added a new check, for broken tags etc.  Which I'm guessing is why these have surfaced during the EE 6 upgrade.

The following is a bit of a breakdown of the tags mentioned above.

```
 {exp:trackback:url}
 {exp:trackback:entries}
```

I believe this add-on was removed starting in version 2.0 https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/installation/version_notes_2.0.html

```
 {exp:referrer} 
 {exp:mailinglist:form}
```

Removed in version 3.0 https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/about/changelog.html

```
{exp:emoticon}
```

Replaced with Emoji module in Version 4 https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/installation/version_notes_4.0.0.html#emoticon-module

So some of these (emoticon) can be updated, others likely removed.  My guess is that the functionality around these tags hasn't been working as intended for a while, or the add-ons we manually updated to support the newer versions of ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 0):

All of these modules have been deprecated in past versions so you'll need to remove those tags from the templates.

```
{exp:mailinglist:form} -v3
{exp:trackback:url} - v2
{exp:trackback:entries} -v2 
{exp:referrer} - v3
{exp:emoticon} -v5
```